# Nservicebus Subscribe Generic DTO

Tags: nservicebus

I have a message want to have generic type as:

```
public class ESBMessageEnvelope<T> : IEvent
{
   public IEnumerable<T> Contents { get; set; }
}
```

but it seems not working when I try to subscribe this message at sub side:

```
await endpoint.Subscribe<ESBMessageEnvelope<EventMessage>>();
```

I think someone asked but answer was not supported 2 years ago , is it a way now?

Comment: I don't think this is supported. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Basically I want put generic type as IEvent, as put ESBMessageEnvelope<T> as bus message, so I can have one handler to handle it, is it possible?

Comment: It's not supported, I'de advise staying away from generic handlers, If you go down that route you'll end up with a bottleneck in your design and will probably end up with a monolith with messaging on top... If you provide the business case, maybe I can help with a solution?